# Jenkins pipeline - deploy to production selected build

Tags: jenkins

We are running a pipeline to build and deploy to the staging enviroment. Suppose some build is good enough and we would like to promote it to the production. How can it be done using Jenkins pipeline? I would like to select a build number and its stored artifacts to be deployed.
I saw this [article](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/deployment/) but it seems to be very naive way.
From my experience in the Freestyle, "[promote plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin)" does a good job, but in the pipeline, its a different story.